# nVidia GT 730 and Unknown Display, resolution settings reset on reboot

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xrandr

This is linked with following post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/667107/lg-19-display-nvidia-gt-730-unknown-display-problem

After figuring out proper refresh rate for my monitor (19" LG LCD, 1360x768 native resolution) I can't find a way to keep my resolution and refresh rate to survive reboot.

I tried to use `.xprofile` file with commands to add specific mode (1360x768 with 59.8Hz refresh rate). When logging in, I can see resolution change for a short time and then sets back to default 1024x768).

Also tried to set it up in nVidia settings application. I have to use Advanced settings because of refresh rate, but those changes made do not persist after reboot.

At the moment, system boots with 1024x768 resolution, and I have to set resolution and refresh rate manually with following command:

```
xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 1360x768 --rate 59.80
```

I am currently using proprietary nVidia driver (version 355.06 from xorg-edgers) and running Ubuntu 15.04.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue and used a workaround to run the command at boot.

Open a text document and paste this into it

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 1360x768 --rate 59.80
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name=Custom Resolution
```

Save it as `res.desktop` and move it to the /.config/autostart folder.

Or to do the same thing using `nvidia-settings` copy this

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="DFP-0: 1360x768_60"
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name=Custom Resolution
```

NOTE: You may need to change `CurrentMetaMode="DFP-0` to `CurrentMetaMode="DFP-1`, depending on the ID of your display (check this in nvidia settings).

Save it as `res.desktop` and move it to the /.config/autostart folder.

```
mv location/of/res.desktop ~/.config/autostart
```

Make it executable

```
sudo chmod +x ~/.config/autostart/res.desktop
```

Now reboot and it should change the resolution when you log in, but like I said its just a workaround, not a fix.

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for your help. As you said, it is a workaround because I still need to manually run `xrandr` command in some cases, but it is much less frequent than on every reboot. I will mark your post as Answered.

Comment: I will give you an alternative to try using `nvidia-settings` instead of `xrandr`, works every time for me

Comment: I did try `nvidia-settings`, but it does not help, same problem as with `xrandr`.